# Cat program in x86 NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I wrote `cat` program in x86 NASM and I would like to know if there is anything that can be improved.

This implementation of `cat` supports:

- Reading from stdin.
- Multiple arguments.

I checked few cases and program behaves exactly like original `cat` command.

I was thinking if I should add labels like `write` even if I wouldn't `jmp` to them, so code would be cleaner.

Code:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ;esi=1
    mov esi, 1

    ;if(argc==1)
    ;goto open
    cmp dword [esp], 1
    jnz open

    ;else
    ;fd=STDIN_FILENO
    mov dword [fd], 0
    jmp read

open:
    ;fd=open(path,oflag)
    mov eax, 5
    mov ebx, [esp+esi*4+4]
    mov ecx, 0
    int 0x80
    mov [fd], eax

read:
    ;bytes_read=read(fd,buf,BUFSIZE)
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, [fd]
    mov ecx, buf
    mov edx, BUFSIZE
    int 0x80

    ;write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,bytes_read)
    mov edx, eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, buf
    int 0x80

    ;if(bytes_read!=0)
    ;goto read
    cmp edx, 0
    jnz read


    ;close(fd)
    mov eax, 6
    mov ebx, [fd]
    int 0x80

    ;esi++
    inc esi

    ;if(esi<argc)
    cmp dword esi, [esp]
    jl open

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

section .data
    BUFSIZE equ 1024

section .bss
    buf resb BUFSIZE
    fd resd 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was thinking if I should add labels like write even if I wouldn't jmp to them, so code would be cleaner.

Writing labels that aren't jumped to is fine. Provided they have meaningful names, it can help to understand the program.

### My comments (not in a particular order)

> ```
> ;esi=1
> mov esi, 1
> ```

This is a redundant comment! I already can see what the instruction does. What I can't know is what the `ESI` register will be used for.

> ```
> ;if(argc==1)
> ;goto open
> cmp dword [esp], 1
> jnz open
> ```

Here the comment does not correspond to the code. The code actually does `if(argc!=1)`.

> ```
> cmp edx, 0
> jnz read
> ```

The more usual way to test for zero would be `test edx, edx`. It has a smaller encoding and is generally a bit faster.

> ```
> mov ebx, 0
> ```

Similarly, zeroing a register is best done using the `xor` instruction (`xor ebx, ebx`). This is both faster and shorter.

> ```
> mov dword [fd], 0
> ```

Your program would not need this instruction at all, if you would move the *fd* variable from the `.bss` section to the `.data` section using `fd dd 0`.

This in turn opens up an opportunity to shorter the code from:

```
    cmp dword [esp], 1
    jnz open
    mov dword [fd], 0
    jmp read
open:
```

to:

```
    cmp dword [esp], 1
    je  read
open:
```

Also note that in conjunction with the `cmp` instruction, it's better to use `je` and `jne`.
In conjunction with the `test` instruction, it's preferable to use `jz` and `jnz`.

`je` and `jz` have an identical encoding but choosing the right instruction mnemonic better expresses what the intention of the code is.

> ```
> ;if(esi<argc)
> cmp dword esi, [esp]
> jl open
> ```

The *argc* is by its very nature an **unsigned** number. After all it's just a count. You should use the conditional jumps that are provided to deal with the unsigned conditions. So better use `jb open` (JumpIfBelow).
Also there's no point in writing the `dword` size-tag. The mention of the dword register `ESI` already dictates the size.

> ```
> mov edx, eax
> mov eax, 4
> mov ebx, 1
> mov ecx, buf
> int 0x80
> ```

I always prefer to write the function number directly above the `int 0x80` instruction. That way it's immediately clear what function is getting invoked. And for perfection I even assign the registers in a sorted manner:

```
mov edx, eax
mov ecx, buf
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80
```

---

### Putting it all together

- not being afraid to write redundant labels
- putting the comments in a separate column for readability
- shaving off one more byte by using the fact that `ESI==1` when `cmp dword [esp], 1` is executed.

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov  esi, 1
    cmp  [esp], esi        ;if(argc==1) goto read
    je   read
open:
    xor  ecx, ecx          ;fd=open(path,oflag)
    mov  ebx, [esp+esi*4+4]
    mov  eax, 5
    int  0x80
    mov  [fd], eax
read:
    mov  edx, BUFSIZE      ;bytes_read=read(fd,buf,BUFSIZE)
    mov  ecx, buf
    mov  ebx, [fd]
    mov  eax, 3
    int  0x80
write:
    mov  edx, eax          ;write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,bytes_read)
    mov  ecx, buf
    mov  ebx, 1
    mov  eax, 4
    int  0x80
more:
    test edx, edx          ;if(bytes_read!=0) goto read
    jnz  read
close:
    mov  ebx, [fd]         ;close(fd)
    mov  eax, 6
    int  0x80
next:
    inc  esi
    cmp  esi, [esp]        ;if(esi<argc)
    jb   open
exit:
    xor  ebx, ebx
    mov  eax, 1
    int  0x80

section .data
    fd   dd 0              ;fd=STDIN_FILENO

section .bss
    BUFSIZE equ 1024
    buf  resb BUFSIZE
```

### Concern

Nowhere in your code do you check for any errors from api calls like `open` or `read`. Imagine what might happen in these cases?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these comments. Can you tell me how do you know that `test` is faster (same with `xor`)? Or how can I check myself is something is faster in NASM? I forgot I can define this variable, so it will be `0` at start and assign other value later. I was always assigning registers "for perfection" starting with `eax`, so it looks like in most programming languages i.e. <function name>(<args>). I'm not checking for errors, cause writing this code took me bit of time and I wanted to know if I'm on right track. I will add error handling later. Thanks for that answer.

Comment: By the way, is there any difference if constant is defined in `.bss` section, not in `.data`?

Comment: Can you also tell me why are you comparing `[esp]` with `esi`, not just `1`? Is it faster when you are using register for that?

Comment: @DeBos99 Ordinarily I would define that constant near the top of the program, even before starting the `.code` section. That way it's sooner clear for the reader what the constant equates to. As for the speed of `test` and `xor`, that's what the architecture tells us. My personal tests back this up.

Comment: @DeBos99 I compared with the register (that happened to contain the value of 1), because that made the instruction exactly 1 byte shorter. Shorter instructions are often (not always) a bit faster.

Comment: Ok, so I should move whole `.bss` section to the top and/or `.data`? In relation to `test` and `xor` could you tell me how could I make such a tests myself or its more complicated process?

Comment: Can you tell me how do you know that this instruction is shorter? I thought that if you are giving constant number instead of whole register, its shorter.

Comment: @DeBos99 No, you can leave the sections in place. Write your `equ` outside of any section. Checking the speed of an instruction is done through repeating the instruction(s) millions of times in a loop and measuring the time it takes.

Comment: @DeBos99 I have the advantage of being an assembler designer myself and so I know the length of almost all the instructions by heart. But anyway, if an instruction contains an immediate number (the 1 in this case), that will nearly always require additional storage.

Comment: I did everything you described in answer and comments and code looks much cleaner, but for some reason executable file that is created is 2 times bigger. Is it cause I used some instruction I didn't use before or I did something wrong?

Comment: @DeBos99 That's probably because now for the first time your program has an actual `.data` section. It's not much but aligment makes it bigger. The original version only truly used a `.bss` section and that is never included in the file itself (because of what it stands for which is **uninitialized data**).

Comment: Oh now I see. There was only constant here that can be anywhere else, so the section was technically empty. Can you tell me if there is any good NASM tutorial? For now I was using [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/), but I see they skipped few bits I needed.

Comment: @DeBos99 I could not suggest to you a tutorial mainly because I've never used one. When writing code for the x86 architecture, you should download the relevant Intel manuals from their website. You could also peek at the Intel Optimization Manual. And where NASM is concerned, I think the accompanying manual should suffice. Good hunting!